# macでtcコマンドを利用したい。

Tags: macos, network

Mac上でnetemを利用する方法をご教示ください。

MacとUbuntuをルータを介して同じLAN上に設置しており、Macのeth0に遅延を入れてubuntuからスループット試験をしようとしています。

```
[Mac netem(eth0)]-------[router]-------[Ubuntu (eth0)]
iperf server                            iperf Client
```

そこでMacでeth0に遅延を投入したところ

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root netem delay 200ms
-bash: tc: command not found
```

というエラーが返ってきてしまいました。

Comment: 少し調べて見ましたが、もしかして OSX 用の netem パッケージは存在しないのではないでしょうか。。。

Comment: ありがとうございました。
 netem パッケージ、無いようですね・・・。アプリでの実現を模索します。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XcodeのNetwork Link Conditionerも試してみました。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
ホストやポートを特定できませんが、UL,DL,DNSの遅延が調整できましたので、
シェルスクリプトから利用できるようにしてみました。

delay.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
open delayon.app
```

delayon.app (AppleScript)

```
tell application "System Preferences"
activate
set current pane to pane "com.apple.Network-Link-Conditioner"
end tell

tell application "System Events"
tell process "System Preferences"
    tell window "Network Link Conditioner"
        click button "ON"
        tell group 1
            click pop up button 1

            click menu item "Wifi" of menu 1 of pop up button 1
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 3):

tcコマンドはbrewにもなさそうですし、Yosemiteではipfwもなくなってしまったのでhttp://mschrag.github.io/ こちらのソフトを使うのが手っ取り早いのではないでしょうか。特定のホスト、特定のポートに対してDelayを入れたり速度を制限したりできます。

Answer (score 2):

OSXは[10.9以降ipfwをdeprect](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/ipfw.8.html)してpfctlにおきかわってるんですが、ipfwでしかやったことがないので、どうしたらいいのんか・・・・
http://www.omakase.org/freebsd/freebsd_pf.html